# How to use HasMany Relationship in AdonisJs

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am trying to do hasMany relationship in my adonisjs project on Post and User model

I have a column of `user_id` in my database column and i have tried the below code

```
posts () {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Post')
  }
```

in my User model but anytime i make a post i get this
`ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`

Answer (score 0):

The `user_id` field in the post model cannot be null.

You can set a default value in the post migration

```
// every post has a default owner
table.integer('user_id').defaultTo(1)
```

or allow the relationship to be null

```
table.integer('user_id').nullable()
```